# How I can fix ORA-01850 hour must be between 0 and 23 problem in Oracle using LPAD

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the following Select statement:

```
SELECT 
pharmacy_employee_details.id,
pharmacy_employee_master.employee_number,
to_char(to_date(pharmacy_employee_master.entry_date,'j'),'dd/MM/yyyy') as ENTRY_DATE,
to_char(to_date (pharmacy_employee_master.entry_time, 'hh24miss'), 'hh:mi:ss') as ENTRY_TIME,
pharmacy_employee_master.beneficiaries,
pharmacy_employee_master.note,
PHARMACY_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.ITEM_CODE,
PHARMACY_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.ITEM_NAME,
PHARMACY_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.QTY,
PHARMACY_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.PRICE 
FROM PHARMACY_EMPLOYEE_MASTER 
INNER JOIN pharmacy_employee_details ON 
pharmacy_employee_details.pid=pharmacy_employee_master.id 
where 1=1
```

The problem arises when the entry time less than 10. How I can fix that using left padding  (LPAD) in oracle?

Comment: I think entry_time column is of type string and has an example data such as  `'30453'` .., ain't it? It's better to store a date in a date type column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that you are storing dates and times as strings (or numbers) and not as dates. You should fix this in the table (if you can).

```sql
ALTER TABLE pharmacy_employee_master ADD ( entry_datetime DATE );

UPDATE pharmacy_employee_master
SET entry_datetime = TO_DATE( entry_date, 'J' )
                     + ( TO_DATE( LPAD( entry_time, 6, '0' ), 'hh24miss' )
                       - TO_DATE( '00:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss' ) );
```

*(Then you an drop the `entry_date` and `entry_time` columns and you don't need to worry about missing leading zeroes and can just format the date and time as you require.)*

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c8730908f5ed68d418345c52c0c4c5f)

If you can't do that then use:

```sql
TO_CHAR(
  TO_DATE( LPAD( entry_time, 6, '0' ), 'hh24miss' ),
  'hh24:mi:ss'
)
```

*(Note: you also want `hh24` rather than `hh` which is just a 12-hour clock; or, if you really do want a 12 hour clock then you probably also want a meridian indicator `'hh12:mi:ss am'`)*

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `LPAD` to pad 0 if length of the entry_time is not 6 as following:

```
to_char(to_date (LPAD(pharmacy_employee_master.entry_time,6,0), 'hh24miss'), 'hh:mi:ss')
```

Cheers!!